# Facebook comment box not working on windows mobile

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, windows-phone-7

Nokia Lumia 800

OS :window 7.10

Browser : IE

Facebook comment is not showing me with above configuration mobile.

Though, its working in other OS mobile. (Android, IOS)

Taken source code from:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/

Ref : http://ottawacitizen.com/news/politics/liberals-allow-some-critical-facebook-comments

Can anybody know, where's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer :
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/473671722773963/

Facebook Developers have consider this as valid bug.